# Есть ли способ не передавать аругмент в url?

Tags: python, django

Как реализовать такое. Ибо если не передать все аргументы в url, будет ошибка
Есть функция к примеру

views.py

```
def func(request, arg1, arg2):
    .........
```

urls.py

```
path('app/<int:arg1>/')
```

Comment: `def func(request, arg1=None, arg2=None):` ?

Comment: @insolor не пойдет, ибо данные с arg1 и arg2 нужны в функции

Comment: аргументы можно упаковать в тело request

Comment: @Jack_oS как это делается?